# How to make multiple radioButtons but only one is always selected where the first is default?

Tags: objective-c, uibutton

I work an Objective-C project and trying to build a multiple radio buttons. Shortly I want to make multiple radioButtons but only one is always selected where the first is default.

I started to try with 2 buttons but I could not achieve exactly what I want. I hope there are nice ways to do that. I am okay with extension as well.

Comment: in short: you want multiple radioButtons but only one is always selected where the first is default?

Comment: You should probably create your own `UIView` subclass to implement the set of radio buttons.  Regardless, you will want an array of buttons. When a button is selected, simply iterate over the array and if the current element in the iteration isn't the button that was just selected, deselect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can group UI elements by placing them in `UIView` and use an KVO observer to take advantage of the extra code.

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) UIView *group;
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self createGroupWithRadios:3 andSelectIndex:0];
}

//a context to make KVO much easier to catch (and less string compare'y)
static void * kRadioGroupContext = &kRadioGroupContext;

-(void)createGroupWithRadios:(int)amount andSelectIndex:(int)idx {
    CGFloat h = 30.0;
    _group = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, h*amount)];
    for (int i=0; i<amount; i++) {
        UIButton *radio = [UIButton buttonWithType:(UIButtonTypeSystem)];
        radio.tag = i;
        radio.selected = i==idx;
        { //style stuff
            radio.frame = CGRectMake(0, h*i, 100, h);
            [radio setTitle:@"off" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [radio setTitle:@"on" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [radio setTitleColor:UIColor.blackColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [radio setTitleColor:UIColor.redColor forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            //[radio setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"active"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            //[radio setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"inactive"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        [radio addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [_group addSubview:radio];
    }
    [self.view addSubview:_group];

    //you can use _group.tag to keep which one is selected and observe it
    _group.tag = idx;
    [_group addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"tag" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:kRadioGroupContext];
}

-(void)radioButtonPressed:(UIButton*)sender {
    _group.tag = sender.tag;
    for (int i=0; i<_group.subviews.count; i++) {
        UIButton *radio = _group.subviews[i];
        radio.selected = radio.tag==sender.tag;
    } 
}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context == kRadioGroupContext) {
        // do something when a new radio is selected
        NSLog(@"selected Radio %lu", _group.tag);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply I will try this next time and keep at my library but I am not sure for my case It seems to me little complicated. I already set the constraints and #selector function written.

Comment: I also I can't make group in UIView the buttons as they already have a superview.

Comment: you can place the UIView group into that superview also. Doesn't hurt, you will need it anyway to catch if one of them has changed its selection and which *state* the selection has. Anyway you will find some ideas in this example to improve your goal. Still an extension to UIButton could be nice too. Or use your superview instead of *_group*

Comment: yes thank you very much I started to think about with your codes I will give feedback soon

Comment: or you go crazy with `sender.superview.subviews` in `radioButtonPressed:` when you know your superview is the only keeper of "radio" buttons

Comment: just telling - you know UIControl is based on UIView. So your group could even be an UIControl which allows you to add an target when the selection changed. Can post an example if needed.

Comment: if you can I will be glad to save to my snippets library. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned `UIControl` **is a subclass of UIView**, which means you can use UIControl to *group your UIButtons together* also. The advantage is adding a Target is easy to catch when there is a new selection made. Downside is you have to think a bit more about styling/layout because that is fixed in code and altering needs more care. The example below uses an NSArray of NSStrings to be spread as titles inside the UIControl's Buttons. So the NSArray count defines how much Buttons are generated in frame height. Should be easy to build multiple choice forms with this.

```
//ButtonSelectGroup.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface ButtonSelectGroup : UIControl
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andTitles:(NSArray<NSString*>*)titles preValue:(NSInteger)idx;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger value;
-(void)setTitles:(NSArray<NSString *> * _Nonnull)titles;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

and

```
//ButtonSelectGroup.m
#import "ButtonSelectGroup.h"

@interface ButtonSelectGroup () {
    NSInteger oldValue;
}
@end

@implementation ButtonSelectGroup
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andTitles:(NSArray<NSString*>*)titles preValue:(NSInteger)idx {
    if (!(self=[super initWithFrame:frame])) return nil;
    [self createGroupWithPreSelectIndex:idx andTitles:titles];
    return self;
}
-(void)createGroupWithPreSelectIndex:(NSInteger)idx andTitles:(NSArray<NSString*>*)titles {
    NSInteger amount = titles.count;
    CGFloat h = self.frame.size.height / amount;
    for (NSInteger i=0; i<amount; i++) {
        UIButton *radio = [UIButton buttonWithType:(UIButtonTypeSystem)];
        radio.tag = i;
        radio.selected = i==idx;
        { //style stuff
            radio.frame = CGRectMake(0, h*i, 100, h);
            [radio setTitle:titles[i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [radio setTitle:titles[i] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        }
        [radio addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self addSubview:radio];
    }
    self.value = idx;
}
-(void)radioButtonPressed:(UIButton*)sender {
    oldValue = _value;
    for (NSInteger i=0; i<self.subviews.count; i++) {
        UIButton *radio = self.subviews[i];
        radio.selected = radio.tag==sender.tag;
    }
    _value = sender.tag;
    if (_value != oldValue) [self sendActionsForControlEvents:(UIControlEventValueChanged)];
}
-(void)setTitles:(NSArray<NSString *> *)titles {
    for (NSInteger i=0; i<self.subviews.count && i<titles.count; i++) {
        UIButton *radio = self.subviews[i];
        [radio setTitle:titles[i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [radio setTitle:titles[i] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    }
}
@end
```

Then use `#import "ButtonSelectGroup.h"` the following way from your ViewController.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ButtonSelectGroup *group = [[ButtonSelectGroup alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 300) andTitles:@[@"even",@"donald",@"duck",@"would",@"concede"] preValue:0];
    [self.view addSubview:group];
    [group addTarget:self action:@selector(singularChoice:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventValueChanged)];
    // and changing all titles again if you wish
    //group.titles = @[@"but",@"not",@"orangeman"];
}
-(void)singularChoice:(id)sender {
    ButtonSelectGroup* group = (ButtonSelectGroup*)sender;
    UIButton *btn = group.subviews[group.value];
    NSLog(@"groups selection = %lu %@",group.value, btn.titleLabel.text);
}
```

Comment: thanks actually I need to edit my question according to your answers but I accept your first answer.